# Как правильно употребить сказуемое при счетном обороте "158 базовых законов"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, количественно-именное-сочетание

На 31 декабря 2017 года в нашей республике действует (действуют) 158 базовых законов.

Answer (score 3):

**На 31 декабря 2017 года в нашей республике действует 158 базовых законов.**

Единственное число указывает **на совокупность предметов.**

Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02)

2. Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов, форма множественного числа – на отдельные предметы. Ср.: В городе строится пять объектов соцкультбыта (**единое нерасчлененное представление о действии**). – В крупнейших городах страны строятся еще пять объектов соцкультбыта (расчлененное представление о действии).